# Android Room relation M:N with anotation @Relation

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I am using Room databse in Android and I have three tables: Customer, Category, CustomerCategory(relation table). Can I somehow use DTO with @Relation anotation to get Category with all Customers in List?

Comment: maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44361824/how-can-i-represent-a-many-to-many-relation-with-android-room

Comment: I found this too. But I cannot full example of DTO and Query with using @Relation.

Comment: You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58424784