# Kotlin convert json string to list of object using Gson

Tags: android, json, android-studio, gson

I have a problem with Kotlin to write code for conversion from JSON String to List of objects.

Normally in Java, it is like this:

```
  Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<SomeOjbect>>() {}.getType();
    List<SomeOjbect> measurements = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    return measurements;
```

However in Kotlin, when i try it like this:

```
   val gson = Gson()
    val type: Type = TypeToken<List<SomeOjbect>>{}.type
    val measurements : List<SomeOjbect> = gson.fromJson(text, type)
    return measurements
```

The IDE Android Studio underlines as error the TypeToken saying:

> Cannot access ' < init > ': it is public/*package*/ in 'TypeToken'

and also underlines as error the {} saying:

> Type mismatch.
>   Required:
>   Type!
>   Found:
>   () → Unit

So is there a solution to make it work for Kotlin?

Comment: Try this, it uses object instead of Type..                                           measurements : List<SomeOjbect> = gson.fromJson(text, object : TypeToken<List<SomeOjbect>>() {}.type)

Comment: @Uttam Thanks, it worked. You can post it as an answer and i accept it

Comment: Glad that it helps you..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could try doing this instead:

```
val objectList = gson.fromJson(json, Array<SomeObject>::class.java).asList()
```

EDIT [14th January 2020]: You should NOT be using GSON anymore. Jake Wharton, one of the projects maintainers, suggests using Moshi, Jackson or kotlinx.serialization.

Comment: Link here: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ejjroe/kotlinx_json_vs_gson_a_short_article_about_kotlin/fcz3v0d?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

Comment: Wow! Thats the biggest change in my android networking stack :D

Answer (score 6):

Try this, it uses object instead of Type..

```
measurements : List<SomeOjbect> = gson.fromJson(text, object : TypeToken<List<SomeOjbect>>() {}.type)
```