# Create Room Entity for a Table which has a field with LONG datatype in Sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

App Database has **Items** table with a column **Price** with datatype **Long**.
Db Version = 1

```
CREATE TABLE items (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,item_id 
INTEGER,title TEXT,price LONG, UNIQUE (item_id) ON CONFLICT IGNORE)
```

While trying to migrate to Room I am experiencing below issue

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle items(moka.pos.test.data.entity.Item).

Expected : price=Column{name='price', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}
Found : price=Column{name='price', type='LONG', affinity='1', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}
```

Here is my entity class for Item

```
@Entity(tableName = "items")
public class Item {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "_id")
private Integer _ID;

@ColumnInfo(name = "item_id")
private Integer id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "title")
private String title;

@ColumnInfo(name = "price")
private Long price;

public Integer get_ID() {
    return _ID;
}

public void set_ID(Integer _ID) {
    this._ID = _ID;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public Long getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(Long price) {
    this.price = (long) (getId() * AppUtil.getRandomNumber(10, 99));
}
}
```

How to make the Room entity field to support Long datatype when migration from SQLiteOpenHelper to Room.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The simple answer is you **CANNOT**

Room only supports 5 data types which are `TEXT`, `INTEGER`, `BLOB`, `REAL` and `UNDEFINED`.

So, java data types of `Boolean`, `Integer`, `Long` will be all converted to `INTEGER` in *SQL*.

What you can do is convert your `LONG` data type to `INTEGER` in *SQL* instead of converting `INTEGER` data type to `LONG` in *Room* in order to make Room support `LONG`, which Room doesn't support.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 9):

As from the docs SQLITE doesn't support Long, check [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) here.

> INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8
>   bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

However as **LONG**  is 8 byte and **INTEGER** can also save values of 8 bytes, you can **use INTEGER**.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: i am a little confused here . do you mean "lNTEGER" type in sql is 8 bytes in size which is same size range as "long"  datatype of java  (8 bytes) ? Because `int` data type is 4bytes in size.

Comment: Hello @anshsachdeva, I believe in the above answer karan has talked about the INTEGER Attribute type in SQL Lite and it's size in SQLite. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @anshsachdeva as cited in the answer, INTEGER in SQLite could have 1,2,3,4,6, or 8 bytes, so you can fit java's 8-byte long Long into SQLite's INTEGER

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still struggling with this...
creating a new database file in SQLite, copy the SQL statement for creating the table but change every datatype to either TEXT, INTEGER, BLOB, REAL and UNDEFINED,.

Then populate the table with copied SQL statement from old DB.

This fixed the problem, where simply changing the datatype in SQLite did not.