# error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it

Tags: kotlin, android-room

My data class to be used as an `Entity` is as follows:

```
@Entity(tableName = "weather_response")
data class CurrentWeatherResponse(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) var id_count: Int = 0,
    @Embedded(prefix = "coord_") val coord: Coord,
    @Embedded(prefix = "details_") @TypeConverters(value = [(DetailTypeConverters::class)]) @SerializedName("weather") val details: List<Details>,
    val base: String,
    @Embedded(prefix = "main_") val main: Main,
    val visibility: Int,
    @Embedded(prefix = "wind_") val wind: Wind,
    val dt: Long,
    @Embedded(prefix = "sys_") val sys: Sys,
    val timezone: Int,
    val name: String,
    val cod: Int
)
```

My details object is a List of a custom class called `Details` - which contains:

```
@Entity(tableName = "details")
data class Details(
    val id: Int,
    val main: String,
    val description: String,
    val icon: String
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) var id_count = 0
}
```

This list will only have one item inside it. As mentioned in the data class above, I also have specified a TypeConverter class for that particular field in the entity. Its definition is below:

```
class DetailTypeConverters: Serializable {
    companion object {
        val gson = Gson()

        @TypeConverter fun detailsToString(details: List<Details>): String {
            return gson.toJson(details)
        }

        @TypeConverter fun stringtoDetails(value: String): List<Details> {
            val type = object : TypeToken<List<Details>>() {}.type
            return gson.fromJson(value, type)
        }
    }
}
```

Just to complete my question, here's my `RoomDatabase` implementation as well:

```
@Database(
    entities = [CurrentWeatherResponse::class,Coord::class,Main::class,Sys::class,Wind::class,Details::class],
    version = 1
)
@TypeConverters(DetailTypeConverters::class)
abstract class ForecastDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun currentWeatherDao(): CurrentWeatherDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile private var instance: ForecastDatabase? = null
        private var LOCK = Any()

        operator fun invoke(context: Context) = instance ?: synchronized(LOCK) {
            instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
        }

        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context) =
            Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, ForecastDatabase::class.java, "forecast.db")
                .build()
    }
}
```

Going with this approach, I get the below error while building the app:

```
C:\Users\Spark\SimpleWeather\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\a5corp\weather\data\network\response\current\CurrentWeatherResponse.java:14: error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
    private final com.a5corp.weather.data.network.response.current.Detail details = null;
```

Even I suspected something wrong because my IDE isn't showing the functions inside the `DetailTypeConverters` to be used anywhere at all. Like this:

[image: IDE not recognizing the functions maybe]

I know a lot of people have also posted solutions for similar kinds of problems in the past on StackOverflow. I did try a lot of them and tried to adapt to what I wanted. The solutions I tried out are:

- [Using another class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44615752/2451763)
- [From a Medium post](https://medium.com/@toddcookevt/android-room-storing-lists-of-objects-766cca57e3f9)
- [Adding @Embedded to the entity field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58299339/2451763)
- [Another TypeConverter, but adapted to Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50256676/2451763)

Each one of them had the same problem - the same error message as posted above was being thrown while building the app. Also in each solution's custom TypeConverter that I had written, the two methods inside would always show the not being used highlighting in my Android Studio.

I'm also considering a move to Realm (if that can make things easier), but I would really like to explore all opportunities to make this work.

Comment: have you checked this @Embedded(prefix = "coord_") val coord: Coord? I think Coord is also a custom class. You have to write TypeConverter for every custom class you use in your entity.

Comment: As long as the details field was commented, my code was working fine, which includes the field `coord` as well. I was able to store to it. That didn't require me to use a `TypeConverter`

Answer (score 0):

Changing `List<Details>` into `ArrayList<Details>` both in the `Entity` as well as the Type Converter class solved this for me.