# How can I fetch list item and add to room database?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Here is the code snippet in where Results data class contains list of objects:

```
@Entity(tableName = "objects_table")
data class Subscriber(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "object_id")
    var id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "object_name")
    var name: Results?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "detected_time")
    var confidence: Results?
```

)

I tried Type converter but simililar error:

```
    @TypeConverter
fun restoreList(listOfString: String?): List<String?>? {
    return Gson().fromJson<List<String?>>(listOfString, object : TypeToken<List<String?>?>() {}.type)
}

@TypeConverter
fun saveList(listOfString: List<String?>?): String? {
    return Gson().toJson(listOfString)
}
```

The error is

```
error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android room persistent library - TypeConverter error of error: Cannot figure out how to save field to database"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44582397/android-room-persistent-library-typeconverter-error-of-error-cannot-figure-ou)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the type converter needed is type converter for the "Results" class not the String list you did

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot to apply your TypeConverter class to your room database.

For example:

Database (note: you can have multiple TypeConverters)

```
@TypeConverters(
    value = [
        MyTypeConverters::class,
        MyOtherTypeConverters::class
    ]
) 
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    ...
}
```

TypeConverter

```
class MyTypeConverters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun restoreList(listOfString: String?): List<String?>? {
        return Gson().fromJson<List<String?>>(listOfString, object : TypeToken<List<String?>?>() {}.type)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun saveList(listOfString: List<String?>?): String? {
        return Gson().toJson(listOfString)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **@Embedded** annotation to your reference type variable.

Like that:

```
@Entity(tableName = "objects_table")
data class Subscriber(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "object_id")
    var id: Int,
    @Embedded(prefix = "name_")
    var name: Results?,
    @Embedded(prefix = "confidence_")
    var confidence: Results?
)
```