# Multiple TypeConverters with Room for primitives

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack

I'm trying to convert 2 different fields to store them in Room DB:

```
@TypeConverters(CategoriesConverter::class, CompressConverter::class)
@Database(
    entities = [Item::class],
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = false
)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() 

@ProvidedTypeConverter
class CategoriesConverter {
    private val separator get() = ", "

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromStringList(value: List<String>): String = value.joinToString(separator)
    
    @TypeConverter
    fun toStringList(data: String): List<String> = data.split(separator)
}

@ProvidedTypeConverter
class CompressConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun compressString(value: String?): ByteArray? = value?.toByteArray()

    @TypeConverter
    fun decompressString(data: ByteArray?): String? = data?.toString()
}

@Entity(tableName = "items")
data class Item(
    @TypeConverters(CompressConverter::class) val img: String? = null,
    @TypeConverters(CategoriesConverter::class) val categories: List<String> = listOf()
)
```

But `CompressConverter` isn't generated at all. If I merge all the conversions in a single class, it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

The converter for the **Item**'s **img** field is not required as Room handles **String** objects.

If the **img** field were not a type that is handled by Room (e.g. not a String, Int, Long ByteArray ....) then a TypeConverter would be required.

**Demo**

Say, for the sake of the answer, if you had a Type such as **MyObject**:-

```
data class MyObject(
    val imgName: String,
    val img: ByteArray
)
```

And then your Item class were:-

```
@Entity(tableName = "items")
data class Item(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long?=null, /* Added as primary key is required */
    //@TypeConverters(CompressConverter::class)
    val img: String? = null,
    //@TypeConverters(CategoriesConverter::class)
    val categories: List<String> = listOf(),
    val otherImg: MyObject /* Added to demonstrate type converter */
)
```

The you could, for example/demonstration, have a **TypeConverter** (albeit it useless other than for demonstration):-

```
class OtherCompressConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun otherCompressMyObject(value: MyObject?): ByteArray = byteArrayOf(0,0,0,0)
    @TypeConverter
    fun decompressMyObject(value: ByteArray): MyObject = MyObject("whatever${value.toString()}", byteArrayOf(1,1,1,1))
}
```

- i.e. This doesn't really convert the actual data (for simplicity) but it rather simply converts the two fields to a single byte array consisting of 4 0 bytes.
- note that the other fields have been retained.

Then with a suitable @Database annotated class e.g. (for the demo):-

```
@TypeConverters(CategoriesConverter::class,CompressConverter::class,OtherCompressConverter::class)
@Database(entities = [Item::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val dao: ItemDao

    companion object {
        private var instance: AppDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,AppDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* for convenience and brevity */
                    //.addTypeConverter(CategoriesConverter::class)
                    //.addTypeConverter(CompressConverter::class)
                    //.addTypeConverter(OtherCompressConverter::class)
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as AppDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

- note that with `@ProvidedTypeConverter` you should use the (commented out) `.addTypeConveter` functions in the build

  - commented out as it's easier/simpler to use the `@TypeConverters` annotation to introduce the converters (introduced at the @Database level provides full scope so no need for the annotation elsewhere).

Now with the above then consider the following activity code (run deom the main thread for simplicity):-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: AppDatabase
    lateinit var dao: ItemDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = AppDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.dao

        dao.insert(Item(img ="Item1ImageString", categories = arrayListOf("AAA","BBB","CCC"), otherImg = MyObject("blah1",
            byteArrayOf(99,98,97,96,95,94,93))
        ))
        dao.insert(Item(img ="Item2ImageString", categories = arrayListOf("DDD"), otherImg = MyObject("blah2",
            byteArrayOf(89,88,87,86,85,84,83))
        ))
        dao.insert(Item(img ="Item3ImageString", categories = arrayListOf(), otherImg = MyObject("blah3",
            byteArrayOf(79,78,77,76,75,74,73))
        ))

        for(i in dao.getAllItems()) {
            val sb = StringBuilder()

            for (imgcat in i.categories) {
                sb.append("\n\tImagCat is ${imgcat}")
            }
            Log.d("DBINFO","Item id is ${i.id} Image(String) is ${i.img} OtherImg-ImgName is ${i.otherImg.imgName} OtherImg- img is ${i.otherImg.img.toString()} ImgCats are:- ${sb}")
        }
    }
}
```

The when run for the first time the results would be:-

**A) The output to the log**:-

```
D/DBINFO: Item id is 1 Image(String) is Item1ImageString OtherImg-ImgName is whatever[B@8f4e6c4 OtherImg- img is [B@3574073 ImgCats are:- 
        ImagCat is AAA
        ImagCat is BBB
        ImagCat is CCC
D/DBINFO: Item id is 2 Image(String) is Item2ImageString OtherImg-ImgName is whatever[B@e2e29ad OtherImg- img is [B@dbbab30 ImgCats are:- 
        ImagCat is DDD
D/DBINFO: Item id is 3 Image(String) is Item3ImageString OtherImg-ImgName is whatever[B@328a4e2 OtherImg- img is [B@e30b3a9 ImgCats are:- 
        ImagCat is
```

- noting that rather than complicate the output of the useless ByteArray 1,1,1,1 the default ByteArray's `toString` method has been used.

**b) The items table has the following data:-**

[image]

So:-

- obviously the data has been saved, and
- the original **img** field  has been saved as is as it was a String and therefore not needing a TypeConverter.
- the **categories** field has been converted from a List to a csv and back (as per the log). Thus the CategoriesTypeConverter has been usitlised.
- the **otherImg** field has been saved BUT instead of adding the complexity of somehow converting the actual data, The TypeConverter simply stores a fixed value of just a ByteArray 0,0,0,0. The output to the log, again via a simplified TypeConverter, just outputs the name as **whatever** and the value of the underlying **imageName** pointer and then ByteArray object's pointer (it's pointer) (the underlying data, due to the simplicity of the TypeConverter is a ByteArray 1,1,1,1 in the returned MyObject).

Comment: Yeah, I found it's possible primitives are not being converted with `TypeConverters` and the alter solution is to generate a new variable for the table and set `@Ignore` for the original one. The problem with custom objects is they can't work with `@Serialize` without extra verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

`img` is nullable `String`, which is a supported type of Room. I guess this is why `CompressConverter` is not created because Room does not need it.

Comment: It's not because it the `String` is nullable, rather because the type is a `String` (nullable or not) which Room handles by default (like it does for Int, Long, ByteArray etc). If the Type were an Object, other than an Object that Room handles, then if there were a TypeConverter that converts the Object (as like `fromStringList` and `toStringList` handling a List<String> object), then the converter would be required/used.

Comment: @MikeT I think that's the same as I said