# How to use nested models in room persistence library?

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

how to relate user table "addressId" column with address table "id" column?
and 
when i insert user model data then how can i insert data in both tables "user and address".
and 
same case in fetching data?

Address model is nested class for user model.

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private Integer localId;

    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private Integer addressId;

    private Address address;
}

@Entity(tableName = "address")
public class Address {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private Integer localId;

    private Integer id;

    private String address1;

    private String address2;

    private String address3;
}
```

Comment: Refer this https://mobikul.com/saving-complex-objects-using-android-room-library/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android room persistent library - how to insert class that has a List object field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44580702/android-room-persistent-library-how-to-insert-class-that-has-a-list-object-fie)

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data

Basically your options are:

- restructure to use different tables
- use `@Embedded`
- using type converter save them in some primitive types (may restrict your ablity to query on these data)