# Not able to use same model for ROOM and Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, android-room

I'm doing an api call, which response includes list of objects, the json response is:

```
[
{
    "name": "jay",
    "age": 27,
    "avatar": "https://avatars.abc/bat_man/",
    "friends": [{
            "friend_name": "abc",
            "friend_age": 23,
            "avatar": "https://avatars.abc/thor/"
        },
        {
            "friend_name": "xyz",
            "friend_age": 26,
            "avatar": "https://avatars.abc/hulk/"
        },
        {
            "friend_name": "pqr",
            "friend_age": 28,
            "avatar": "https://avatars.abc/iron_man/"
        }
    ]
},

{
    "name": "ajay",
    "age": 27,
    "avatar": "https://avatars.abc/bat_man/",
    "friends": [{
            "friend_name": "abc",
            "friend_age": 23,
            "avatar": "https://avatars.abc/thor/"
        },
        {
            "friend_name": "xyz",
            "friend_age": 26,
            "avatar": "https://avatars.abc/hulk/"
        },
        {
            "friend_name": "pqr",
            "friend_age": 28,
            "avatar": "https://avatars.abc/iron_man/"
        }
     ]
  }

]
```

I created a model without the `friends` property, as soon as I added a List of `Friend` I was not able to use room, Now the model I created will work for RetroFit, but it will not work for Room, since Room doesn't support List Objects inside entity.

I fixed it using `@TypeConverter`, but after that the retrofit stopped working.
I'm looking for an approach, so that I can use the same Model for both(api call + persisting the data through room).

I tried to make the model to work with ROOM, but after that my retrofit api callback is coming to `onFailure()` for the obvious reason that it is not getting parsed, the error I'm receiving is `Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe`.

Is there is any way so I ignore some particular property in Retrofit call, and use same model for both purpose.

My model looks :

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_table")
public class User {
    private String name;
    private String href;
    private String avatar;
    private Friends friend;

public User(String name, String href, String avatar, Friends friend) {
    this.name = name;
    this.href = href;
    this.avatar = avatar;
    this.friend = friend;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getHref() {
    return href;
}

public void setHref(String href) {
    this.href = href;
}

public String getAvatar() {
    return avatar;
}

public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
    this.avatar = avatar;
}

public Friends getFriend() {
    return friend;
}

public void setFriend(Friends friend) {
    this.friend = friend;
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you saving the friends list? You should have your friends in another table and use a Foreign Key in Room.

Comment: Did you check json key `friends` with the `friend` field of `Entity`? Btw instead of creating Friends object you can directly write `List` here and create typeconverter for it.

Comment: You can read more about `List Conversion` here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44580702/android-room-persistent-library-how-to-insert-class-that-has-a-list-object-fie

Answer (score 1):

You can use your first approach by annotating with `@Ignore` the fields you want to ignore in room

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_table")
public class User {
    private String name;
    private String href;
    private String avatar;
    @Ignore private Friends friend;
```

Assuming you have in your Dao something like this

@Dao

```
public interface MyDao {

    @Insert
    public void insertUser(User user);

    @Insert
    public void insertFriends(List<Friend> friends);
}
```

Then you can add your data as follows

```
myDao.insertUser(user)
myDao.insertFriends(user.getFriend())
```

Using this approach, there are some changes you'll have to do:

- Instead of a `Friends` object, the User class must have a List of `Friend` object.
- You have to create a table Friends with the appropiate Foreign Keys (this includes adding a userId field to the friends object)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't helped me, I want to ignore it for RetroFit not Room. still I tried this and the result was same, my retrofit call is failing.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried to use the @Expose annotation? That's what I use when I want to ignore a field in retrofit