# Room "Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type"

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, dao

I'm new to android development and I'm working on a project called " water drink reminder " .
this is my Dao and database codes.
i'm getting "***Room Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type"*** error every time I run the app. so I searched about this and what I gained was ***"*** ***don't use LiveData with suspend keyword"***. I didn't use these two together but I still get this error. anyone can help?

```
@Dao

interface Dao {
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertUser(user :User)

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertDrinkData(drink: Drink)

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertNotificationInfo(notification : Notification)

@Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun updateUser(user: User)

@Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun updateNotificationInfo(notification: Notification)

@Delete
suspend fun deleteSelectedDrinkData(drink : Drink)

@Query("SELECT *FROM User_table")
fun getAllUsers() : LiveData<List<User>>

@Query("SELECT * FROM $USER_TABLE_NAME LIMIT 1")
suspend fun readUserData() : User

@Query("SELECT * FROM $USER_TABLE_NAME LIMIT 1")
fun readData() : LiveData<User>

@Query("SELECT * FROM $USER_TABLE_NAME LIMIT 1")
suspend fun readNotificationData() : Notification

@Query("SELECT $COLUMN_DATE_DRINK , SUM($COLUMN_AMOUNT_DRINK) as Total GROUP BY $COLUMN_DATE_DRINK")
suspend fun readDrinkSumData() : MutableList<Sum>

@Query("SELECT $COLUMN_DATE_DRINK , SUM($COLUMN_AMOUNT_DRINK) as Total GROUP BY $COLUMN_DATE_DRINK")
fun readDrinkData() : LiveData<MutableList<Sum>>

@Query("SELECT * FROM $USER_TABLE_NAME WHERE $COLUMN_DATE_DRINK = :date")
suspend fun readDrinkDataSelectedDay(date:String): MutableList<Drink>
```

}

```
@Database(entities = [User::class,Drink::class,Notification::class],
version = DATABASE_VERSION)abstract class AppDataBase : RoomDatabase() {
abstract val daoInstance : Dao
companion object {
    private var INSTANCE : AppDataBase? = null
    fun getInstance(context : Context) : AppDataBase {
        synchronized(this) {
            var instance : AppDataBase? = INSTANCE
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    AppDataBase::class.java,
                    "AppDataBase"
                ).build()
            }
            return instance
        }
    }
}}


class AppRepository(private val dao: Dao) {

fun readData() : LiveData<User> = dao.readData()
fun readDrinkData(): LiveData<MutableList<Sum>> = dao.readDrinkData()
suspend fun insertUser(user :User): Unit = dao.insertUser(user)
suspend fun insertDrinkData(drink: Drink): Unit = dao.insertDrinkData(drink)
suspend fun insertNotificationInfo(notification : Notification): Unit = dao.insertNotificationInfo(notification)
suspend fun updateUser(user: User) : Unit = dao.updateUser(user)
suspend fun updateNotificationInfo(notification: Notification): Unit = dao.updateNotificationInfo(notification)
suspend fun readUserData() : User = dao.readUserData()
suspend fun readNotificationData() : Notification = dao.readNotificationData()
suspend fun deleteSelectedDrinkData(drink : Drink): Unit = dao.deleteSelectedDrinkData(drink)
suspend fun readDrinkSumData(): MutableList<Sum>? = dao.readDrinkSumData()
suspend fun readDrinkDataSelectedDay(date: String): MutableList<Drink>? {
    return dao.readDrinkDataSelectedDay(date)
}
```

**this is my room version : 2.4.2**

and this is errors :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jCiD.png)

Comment: Perhaps you accidentally imported the `Notification` from the Android SDK, rather than your own.

Comment: Same problem here. Yesterday we build our project without issue and today we found this error without changing any line of code. Due to the timing coincidence I guess this could be a bug introduced by a recent update of AS.

Comment: @JoeAspara that's so annoying, i want to work on my project but this error is driving me crazy :((

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you but it wasn't that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't use `LiveData` as the return type.
Use:

```
fun readDrinkData() : MutableList<Sum>
```

Instead of:

```
fun readDrinkData() : LiveData<MutableList<Sum>>
```

---

In case you want to use complex objects in your room models, You have to add a Room-Converter for those types. Read this: [Referencing complex data using Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data).
For example you can use `GSON` to convert them to a `json-string`

```
class MyModel (
    var key: String,
    var value: String,
)

class MySuperModel (
    var name: String,
    var data: MyModel,
)
```

```
object Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromJsonString(String srtJson): MyModel {
        return Gson().fromJson(srtJson, MyModel.class);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toJsonString(MyModel data): String {
        return Gson().toJson(data);
    }
}
```

Then you have to add your converters to your database:

```
@Database(entities = {MySuperModel.class})
@TypeConverters({Converters.class})
class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase
```

Comment: hi, I deleted live data but I still get this error for other functions which have queries except for the first three ones. it means these functions make an error: **readDrinkData, readDrinkDataSelectedDay, readDrinkSumData, readNotificationData** check this out [link](https://usaupload.com/6FaI/Screenshot_(409).png)

Comment: That's something else. You have to add a Room-Converter for complex types. Read this: [Referencing complex data using Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data)

Answer (score -1):

You are using suspend keyword in code like following:
suspend fun readUserData() : User = dao.readUserData()
so it throws the related error.
I suggest you to not use LiveData in this layer. you will probably face other issues soon. just return the data entity and update live data in view model.

Comment: hi, I deleted live data but I still get this error for other functions which have queries except for the first three ones. it means these functions make an error: **readDrinkData, readDrinkDataSelectedDay, readDrinkSumData, readNotificationData** check this out [link](https://usaupload.com/6FaI/Screenshot_(409).png)

Comment: Seems like you need a converter class for mutable list
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48260739/8885332

Comment: sorry, but can you explain to me covert mutable list to what return type?

Comment: Using converter you can convert a list of any type to a string and vice versa.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data