# Room Persistence @Relation working in Java but not in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components

Base on my previous question ([Android Persistence room: "Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330452/android-persistence-room-cannot-figure-out-how-to-read-this-field-from-a-curso)) which I got to work thanks the feedback, I implemented the same example in Kolin (see code below). I had to make some minor changes like the parameters that are now passed to a the query which have to be passed as "p0", "p1" etc. 
Now in Kotlin I get the following error related to the UserWithPets class:

**error: Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor.
e:     private java.util.List pets;**

```
@Dao
interface UserDAO {   

    @get:Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    val all: LiveData<List<User>>

    @Insert
    fun insertUser(user: User) //single one

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertUsers(vararg users: User)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM User")
    fun loadUsersWithPets(): LiveData<List<UserWithPets>>

}


@Entity
class Pet( var name: String?,  var ownerId: Int,@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)var id:Int)



@Dao
interface PetDAO {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM pet")
    val all: List<Pet>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM pet WHERE id IN (:p0)")
    fun loadAllByIds(petIds: IntArray): List<Pet>


    @Insert
    fun insert(pet: Pet)

    @Insert
    fun insertAll(vararg pets: Pet)

    @Delete
    fun delete(user: Pet)
}


class UserWithPets {
    @Embedded
    var user: User? = null

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "ownerId", entity = Pet::class)
    var pets: List<Pet>? = null
}
```

It appears that if I write the `UserWithPets` class in Java it will work fine, but fails when it is written in Kotlin. Any ideas what is wrong? Is this an annotation processing issue?

Comment: Try `List<@JvmSuppressWildcards Pet>`. Docs: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-suppress-wildcards/

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. It doesn't work with Kotlin class

Comment: I created this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62778467 cause I couldn't solve it.

Comment: cool awesome, our short-term solution was to write the Entities in Java and the rest in Kotlin which still works. Let's hope google fixes it anytime soon

Comment: Yeah @AndreaSoro

Comment: Are you still having this issue? I am experiencing the same thing in Kotlin.

Comment: I have an example application of this on GitHub - Look at the AccountTransactions.java class, if you convert it to Kotlin the integration tests no longer pass - https://github.com/adammc331/roomtutorial

Comment: Are you using the Kotlin Annotation Processor in your build.gradle file?

`kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"`

Comment: Do you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update room to 1.0.0-alpha8 and add List<@JvmSuppressWildcards Pet>.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your query @Query("SELECT * FROM pet WHERE id IN (:p0)")

to 
    `@Query("SELECT * FROM pet WHERE id IN (:petIds)")`

There was an issue between kotlin and Room lib, Kotlin wasn't preserving the actual parameter names of the arguments properly, so (:p0)/(:arg0) was work around that, its resolved now.

I hope this will resolve the issue