# Android Room Pojo Object inconsist functionality

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

During development I face situation where I have to save **Object with fields and List**

Looking for the solution I came across Room `@Relation`

I've damm [UserAndPets](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation.html) example

```
class ShoppingListAndItems(
    @Embedded
    var shoppingList: ShoppingListCache = ShoppingListCache.emptyInstance(),
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = ShoppingListCache.COLUMN_PARENT_ID,
        entityColumn = ShoppingItemCache.ENTITY_COLUMN)
    var shoppingItems: List<ShoppingItemCache> = emptyList()
)
```

The problem with that kind solution, using following DAO - list is not being updated:

```
@Query("""SELECT * FROM ${ShoppingListCache.TABLE_NAME}
    WHERE ${ShoppingListCache.COLUMN_IS_ARCHIVED} = :isArchived""")
fun getListOfShoppingList(isArchived: Boolean): List<ShoppingListAndItems>
```

Moreover that POJO cannot be use more then return type - what is disappointing

```
@Insert
fun insertShoppingListAndItems(newShoppingListAndItems: ShoppingListAndItems) // Error

@Delete
fun insertShoppingListAndItems(newShoppingListAndItems: ShoppingListAndItems) // Error
```

Am I doing something wrong or Room doesn't support such functionality?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Room: Insert relation entities using Room](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44667160/android-room-insert-relation-entities-using-room)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a non-entity with `@Insert`, `@Update`, `@Delete`. Honestly, there is no native solution to use non-entity class with any of the above annotation, but there are few workarounds.

Take a look at this already answered question showcasing various workarounds to do:
[Android Room: Insert relation entities using Room](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44667160/android-room-insert-relation-entities-using-room)