# Room relation between table issues

Tags: android, android-room

I am quite familiar with the relation among tables, especially when used SQLite.
Recently I moved to Room with MVVM clean architecture in mind, I came to a lot of confusion during establishing a relation.

For simplicity, I am fetching the Github repo list and storing in DB using Room.

Here's JSON

```html
[
{
"author": "idealvin",
"name": "co",
"avatar": "https://github.com/idealvin.png",
"url": "https://github.com/idealvin/co",
"description": "An elegant and efficient C++ basic library for Linux, Windows and Mac.",
"language": "C++",
"languageColor": "#f34b7d",
"stars": 635,
"forks": 82,
"currentPeriodStars": 130,
"builtBy": [
{
"username": "idealvin",
"href": "https://github.com/idealvin",
"avatar": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/12691466"
},
{
"username": "frederick-vs-ja",
"href": "https://github.com/frederick-vs-ja",
"avatar": "https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/23228989"
},
{
"username": "FrankHB",
"href": "https://github.com/FrankHB",
"avatar": "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/1857647"
}
]
},
{
"author": "alyssaxuu",
"name": "flowy",
"avatar": "https://github.com/alyssaxuu.png",
"url": "https://github.com/alyssaxuu/flowy",
"description": "The minimal javascript library to create flowcharts ✨",
"language": "JavaScript",
"languageColor": "#f1e05a",
"stars": 1841,
"forks": 58,
"currentPeriodStars": 459,
"builtBy": [
{
"username": "alyssaxuu",
"href": "https://github.com/alyssaxuu",
"avatar": "https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/7581348"
},
{
"username": "artmsilva",
"href": "https://github.com/artmsilva",
"avatar": "https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/347490"
}
]
}
]
```

This are my Entity classes.

```css
@Entity
data class GithubEntity(


    // Ignore this field during Serialization and De-Serialization
    // PK  (AUTO INC)
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "rowId")
    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false) var rowId: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "author")
    @SerializedName("author")
    @Expose var author: String? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose var name: String? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "avatar")
    @SerializedName("avatar")
    @Expose var avatar: String? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "url")
    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose var url: String? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose var description: String? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "language")
    @SerializedName("language")
    @Expose var language: String? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "languageColor")
    @SerializedName("languageColor")
    @Expose var languageColor: String? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "stars")
    @SerializedName("stars")
    @Expose var stars: Int? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "forks")
    @SerializedName("forks")
    @Expose var forks: Int? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "currentPeriodStars")
    @SerializedName("currentPeriodStars")
    @Expose var currentPeriodStars: Int? = null,


   
    @SerializedName("builtBy")
    @Expose var builtByList: List<BuiltByEntity>? = null


) {

    constructor() : this(
        0, "", "", "", "",
        "", "", "", 0, 0, 0, null
    )

}
```

```css
@Entity(
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = GithubEntity::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("rowId"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("rowFkId"),
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )]
)
data class BuiltByEntity(

    // PK (AUTO INC)
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "row_Built_Id")
    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false) var rowId: Int,


    // FOREIGN KEY -> rowId (PK) of GitHubEntity
    @ColumnInfo(name = "rowFkId")
    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false) var rowFkId: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "username")
    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose var username: String? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "href")
    @SerializedName("href")
    @Expose var href: String? = null,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "avatar")
    @SerializedName("avatar")
    @Expose var avatar: String? = null
) {

    constructor() : this(0, 0, "", "", "")
}
```

And my AppDataBase class

```
   @Database(entities = [GithubEntity::class, BuiltByEntity::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(BuiltByConverter::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
```

So, I was expecting a kind of output like this

GitHubEntity's rowId (PK) is being used as FK in BuiltByEnity rowFkId(FK)

[image]

SO, when I debugged using stetho, Here's the output I got

[image]

[image]

I am finding difficulty to turn my around with Room.
Could you highlight what should be modified and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to fix is to remove this:

```
@SerializedName("builtBy")
@Expose var builtByList: List<BuiltByEntity>? = null
```

from GithubEntity. Insert a GithubEntity item and by its id insert BuiltByEntity.

You see, it is nasty. Notice that there is no native way to insert with relations in room. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44667160/android-room-insert-relation-entities-using-room) question and answers for best practices.

**Update:**

Read this article too: [Android Room Database Tips and Tricks](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/04/01/android-room-tips/)

Comment: Hi @Sina, I used to do that when using the SQLite way. I went to that post (highlighted above) thoroughly earlier and kind of expecting that, this behavior might have changed now. I just wanted to confirm !!

Comment: As I know, it has not changed yet. We all bear the same pain here :)

Comment: I've just found what was very helpful for me on the subject. I updated my answer.