# How to represent nested @Relation with Android Room?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components

Here is my POJO in kotlin:

```
data class Pass(var uuid: String,
                var activationRestrictions:List<ActivationRestriction>)


data class ActivationRestriction(var uuid: String,
                                 var activationRestrictionExceptions:List<ActivationRestrictionException>)


data class ActivationRestrictionException(var uuid: String)
```

How can I represent this nested relation with Room? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330452/android-persistence-room-cannot-figure-out-how-to-read-this-field-from-a-curso/44424148#44424148) is one of the solution, but it does not contain a nested relation. I am specifically looking for solving a nested relationship with Room.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Relation` annotation for POJO classes.

> A convenience annotation which can be used in a Pojo to automatically
>   fetch relation entities. When the Pojo is returned from a query, all
>   of its relations are also fetched by Room.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation.html) is the documentation.

Also, this answer has more details: [Android Persistence room: "Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330452/android-persistence-room-cannot-figure-out-how-to-read-this-field-from-a-curso/44424148#44424148)

Comment: I rephrased my question. So now how do I solve my problem?