# How to use Room Relation to get a list of another pojo

Tags: android, foreign-keys, android-room

```
@Entity(tableName = "subscription")
data class Subscription(
    @PrimaryKey val planId: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "plan_name") val planName: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "plan_description") val planDescription: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "plan_reg_fee") val planRegFee: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "plan_monthly_charge") val planMonthlyCharge: String? = null
)


data class Benefit(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "benefit_id") val benefitId: Int? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "benefit_code") val benefitCode: Int? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "benefit_name") val benefitName: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "benefit_status") val benefitStatus: String? = null
)
```

how to get a  list of Benefit inside Subscription i.e.,

```
val benefitList: LiveData<List<Benefit>>? = null
```

using Room relation

Comment: followed from this post  [https://stackoverflow.com/a/44424148/8601451]

Answer (score 0):

You can find examples from [Google Documents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation).
There are examples about Relation in Room.

Comment: yeah i referred to this but i am not able to get a successful build

Comment: [There is](https://medium.com/@magdamiu/android-room-persistence-library-relations-75bbe02e8522)  an example in Java.

[There is](https://medium.com/mindorks/room-kotlin-android-architecture-components-71cad5a1bb35) an example in Kotlin.

I hope,it will help you.

Comment: followed from this post [https://stackoverflow.com/a/44424148/8601451].          Is there some way without using @TypeConverters?